# What does the SciKit FastICA return and what is the difference between FastICA and fastica (both return different values)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the scikit learn module for Machine Learning exercises at school. The exercise I'm trying to reconstruct is already given as an example on the sklearn ICA documentation, The Blind Source Separation Using ICA [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html#example-decomposition-plot-ica-blind-source-separation-py]. This example basically generates 3 signals (or sources of sound), merges then with added noise and then attempts to reconstruct the original sources using ICA. Simple enough, right? However, I have the following confusions:

1. What exactly is does the FastICA return? For the following piece of code:

   ```
   ica = FastICA(n_components=3)
   S_rec = ica.fit_transform(X)
   ```

   What is 'ica' in this case? I tried to print the value, but nothing was returned. I'm trying to find out what 'ica' is in order to understand exactly what ica.fit_transform(X) is doing. What transformation is being applied to 'X' here?
2. What is th difference between 'FastICA' and 'fastica'? The two functions also have different documentation pages:

   - FastICA: http: //scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FastICA.html#sklearn.decomposition.FastICA
   - fastica: http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.fastica.html

   My question here being, both of them return different mixing matrices for the same input data. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong to the best of my understanding.

If someone could explain this or point out if i'm doing something wrong, it would be a great help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly is does the FastICA return? For the following piece of code:
>    [...] What is 'ica' in this case?

FastICA is a class, thus call to it returns an OOP wrapper over .fastica function. In other words, you get a reference to an instance of FastICA class, which stores your initial configuration (such as number of components) and can be used to perform ica on any data (through fit/transform).

> I tried to print the value, but nothing was returned. I'm trying to find out what 'ica' is in order to understand exactly what ica.fit_transform(X) is doing. What transformation is being applied to 'X' here?

ICA finds the **unmixing** matrix W, which is then applied to X, thus fit_transform(X) == X.dot(W) (+ some whitening etc. if you requested it in the constructor)

> What is th difference between 'FastICA' and 'fastica'? The two functions also have different documentation pages:

There is no difference. FastICA is an object oriented wrapper around fastica, nothing more. It actually [calls fastica during fit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/decomposition/fastica_.py#L474).

> My question here being, both of them return different mixing matrices for the same input data. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong to the best of my understanding.

FastICA is not a deterministic algorithm, thus you can get different solutions each time.

Comment: Dear @lejlot does FastICA always give us different results? even if we set the random_state ?

Comment: if i have `X = M(mixing) * S(sources)`, after running `ica.fit_transform(X)` how can I get the matrix `S`?